# Reversing list with sublists and atoms in lisp

Tags: scheme, lisp

I am new to a functional programming and trying to reverse a list in lisp. List consists of sublists and atoms. The function `(reverse-tree '((1 2) 5 6 (3)))` should return `((3) 6 5 (2 1))`. Here is my function:

```
(define (reverse-tree s)
    ;; giving problem with an atom 
  (if (not(list? s)) ( reverse-tree s) (reverse (map reverse s)))

  )
```

It works when I do `(reverse-tree '((1 2) (3)))` => `((3) (2 1))`. But it crashes when I do `(reverse-tree '((1 2) 5 6 (3)))`. The error I am getting is `reverse: contract violation  expected: list?`

**I am limited to use only: `reverse, map, if, cond, list? null?` functions.**

EDIT, someone marked this question as duplicate, but *there is a restriction* in this problem, which is not similar to the other question. I *cannot use* `cons`, `car`, `cdr`, `append`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the problem in pieces. First, if the function is given a list as an argument, you need to reverse that list. That's easy, something like:

```
(define (reverse-tree tree)
  (if (list? tree)
      (reverse tree)
      ...))
```

But you also need to reverse all sublists in it and all sublists in them and so on. Since that's exactly what our `reverse-tree` does, we should use `map` to apply it to all elements in the reversed list (it doesn't actually matter whether you use `map` before or after reversing the list):

```
(define (reverse-tree tree)
  (if (list? tree)
      (map reverse-tree (reverse tree))
      ...))
```

But if the input is `((1 2) 3 4 (5 6))`, the `map` will call `reverse-tree` on the atoms `3` and `4` too. It wouldn't make any sense to reverse them, so we can just return them:

```
(define (reverse-tree tree)
  (if (list? tree) 
      (map reverse-tree (reverse tree))
      tree))
```

Now it should work:

```
(reverse-tree '((1 2) 3 4 (5 6)))
;=> ((6 5) 4 3 (2 1))
(reverse-tree '((1 2) 3 4 (5 6 (7 8))))
;=> (((8 7) 6 5) 4 3 (2 1))
```

Comment: I see, my problem was that I was  not returning the atom. Thanks!